# R How do I merge polygon features in a shapefile with many polygons? (reproducible code example)

Tags: r, merge, polygon, shapefile

**How do I merge polygon features in a shapefile with many polygons?**

rbind and union just combine the rows of the shapefile features, they don't actually merge the polygons themselves.

**Desired result in example below:**

How do I get the below shapefile with duplicated ID_2 to merge to a single polygon in sptemp?

Example below of GADM level 2 of Ethiopia has first two rows of the shapefile ID_2 column duplicated (value=1). I'd like sptemp with 79 features combining the first two rows that are the ones with duplicated ID_2. A plot of sptemp[1,] would bring up where current sptemp[1,] and sptemp2[2,] without the boundaries between the duplicated, i.e. the polygons are merged too.

Example Code:

Download, unzip, and load into R GADM file for Ethiopia level 2 (899kb to working directory):

```
library(curl)
library(rgdal)

curl_download("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.8/shp/ETH_adm_shp.zip",
              destfile=paste0("gadmETH.zip"),
              quiet=FALSE)

unzip(paste0("gadmETH.zip"), exdir="gadmETH", overwrite=FALSE) 


###Load shapefile
sptemp <- readOGR(dsn="gadmETH", layer="ETH_adm2")
```

The ID_2 column for the first two polygons is duplicated

```
###You'll see in the first two rows ID_2 is duplicated
df.sptemp <- as.data.frame(sptemp)

View(sptemp)

###I can't just delete one because they are separate polygons 
plot(sptemp[1,], col="blue")
plot(sptemp[2,], add=TRUE, col="red" )
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Note** This method uses `st_union`, which combines all the 'multipolygons' into single polygons. This may not be your actual desired result.

---

If you use `library(sf)` as opposed to `sp` (it's the successor to `sp`), you can use `st_union` to join geometries.

You can do this inside a `dplyr` pipe sequence too.

```
library(sf)
sptemp <- sf::st_read(dsn = "~/Desktop/gadmETH/", layer = "ETH_adm2")

library(dplyr)

sptemp %>% 
    group_by(ID_2) %>%
    summarise(geometry = sf::st_union(geometry)) %>%
    ungroup()

# Simple feature collection with 79 features and 1 field
# geometry type:  GEOMETRY
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: 33.00154 ymin: 3.398823 xmax: 47.95823 ymax: 14.84548
# epsg (SRID):    4326
# proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
# # A tibble: 79 x 2
#      ID_2                       geometry
#     <dbl>         <sf_geometry [degree]>
#   1    1. POLYGON ((38.85556 8.938293...
#   2    2. POLYGON ((42.15579 12.72123...
#   3    3. POLYGON ((40.17299 14.49028...
#   4    4. POLYGON ((41.11739 10.93207...
#   5    5. POLYGON ((40.61546 12.7958,...
#   6    6. POLYGON ((40.25209 11.24655...
#   7    7. POLYGON ((36.35452 12.04507...
#   8    8. POLYGON ((40.11263 10.87277...
#   9    9. POLYGON ((37.39736 11.60206...
#   10   10. POLYGON ((38.48427 12.32812...
#  # ... with 69 more rows
```

Comment: This works great! And thanks for the tip on sf! Is there a downside to loading a shapefile in sf? I'm getting crazy loading performance differences (Ethiopia 2 in rgdal: user system elapsed 
  0.999   0.211   1.271, same layer in sf:   user  system elapsed 
  0.013   0.003   0.017). I tested a bunch of other processes like extract and velox extract and all seem to work fine with sf shapefiles instead of rgdal. Is there a downside to loading shapefiles in sf over rgdal or is the performance boost a pure factor of the update (maybe a loading process move to C or something?)?

Comment: @NealBarsch see the [Benchmarking section in the first sf vignette](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf1.html#reading-and-writing) for a brief discussion on performance. Any other information is usually linked in [the sf github page](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf)

Comment: @NealBarsch - do be aware of the impact of using `st_union`. It's merging all the multipolygons into single polygons. You're essentially changing the shape

Comment: Intention is to use the updated list for extent boundaries in raster extraction so shouldn't be an issue as long as I don't delete any area.

Comment: @NealBarsch - OK cool. I'll keep the 'note' at the top so others who see this are aware.