# R sf & dplyr: summarise fails despite compatible types across groups

Tags: r, dplyr, backwards-compatibility, r-sf

As of dplyr (0.8.3) and sf (0.8.0), the following was possible (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49354480/9164265):

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
nc %>%
  group_by(SID74) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_union(geometry)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This would have had the effect of combining each geometry with the same `SID74` into their own `MULTIPOLYGON`s.

However, this now (dplyr 1.0.0) gives the following error:

```
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `geometry`.
x Input `geometry` must return compatible vectors across groups
ℹ Input `geometry` is `st_union(geometry)`.
ℹ Result type for group 1 (SID74 = 0): <sfc_MULTIPOLYGON>.
ℹ Result type for group 2 (SID74 = 1): <sfc_MULTIPOLYGON>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Does anyone know why dplyr is throwing this error, despite the types evidently being of the same `<sfc_MULTIPOLYGON>` class?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. I'm using `dplyr 1.0.0` and I don't get your error message.

Comment: Me neither with dplyr 1.0.0 and sf 0.9.5

Comment: There have been enormous changes with `sf`, primarily related to how Proj is handled, and things are now in Proj-6.3 - Proj-7+ land. I would imagine sf-0.8.0 was back in Proj-4. Over at [r-sig-geo](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-geo) they've been banging the drum to update or be left in the dust. You have found the dust. These were all necessary, breaking changes. Update, upgrade. It will be better.

Comment: I have upgraded... and it is better :) Thanks for pointing this out to me, while I thought to upgrade `dplyr` I didn't think to check whether my `sf` was still in date.
Re reproducibility... I can only imagine this is due to the later versions of `sf` you are likely using.
Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Write up what you did to resolve the problem as an answer, then after a little wait, you can accept your own answer. This is useful because this is the Q/A process, virtuous circle, and you gain rep besides. And welcome to SO.

Comment: Although my solution (upgrade) solved the problem I had, it is not exactly an answer to the question - I don't think the error above should have been raised. I'll add this as an answer all the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error no longer appears when upgrading `sf 0.8.0 --> 0.9.5`.
Although this does not explain the error (using `dplyr 1.0.0` & `sf 0.8.0`) itself, it would make sense to upgrade all packages being used in conjunction with `dplyr` when the latter is being upgraded (especially by a major version as is the case here).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a reproducible example for this (I'm under a deadline right now), but I'm getting a similar error when I run some code:

`df <- df %>% group_by(case_id) %>% dplyr::mutate(status_official = last(na.omit(status)))`

Where the data has from 1 to 30 rows per case_id.  I think that the problem is that some of the cases don't have a non-missing value for status, while some so.  When I filter out the rows with missing status values, I don't get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I received a similar error when I was trying to group dates that were either a numeric or NA_Date_. I resolved the problem by using NA instead of NA_Date_.

It's worth going through your code to try and spot where similar inconsistencies might be creeping in.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).